# Suggestions to Initialize A Non-Aggregate With An Initializer List with VS 2012

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, porting

I want to compile a very old application using VS 2012. It is written in C and was written sometime during the nineties. I have made a series of code changes but I am having an issue with one.
Currently, I get the "non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list" list error with VS 2012.
After a bit of research, I see what is happening and why it is happening with VS 2012.
However, I would like suggestions on how I can change this in a manner that will support compiling on multiple platforms. Note that my intent is to rewrite good chunks of this but in the meantime, I want to be able to compile and check it.

The definition of the structure is:

```
struct plantbl {
  char max_harmonic[9];
  char max_power_of_t;
  signed char *arg_tbl;
  double *lon_tbl;
  double *lat_tbl;
  double *rad_tbl;
  double distance;
};
```

The structure is defined in a header (two actually)

An instance is declared and initialized like this:

```
static struct plantbl mer404 = {
  { 11, 14, 10, 11,  4,  5,  2,  0,  0,},
  6,
  merargs,
  mertabl,
  mertabb,
  mertabr,
  3.8709830979999998e-01,
};
```

The mer* variables are arrays defined like this:

```
static signed char merargs[] = { ... long++ list of values };
```

The mer404 variable is declared, defined, and initialized in the global namespace in what was a c file. There are no functions in this file.

Compilation fails with:

```
error C2552: 'mer404' : non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list
```

After a bit of research, reading, and contemplation of what I read, I understand what is happening and why.
I am looking for suggestions that will allow me to compile the application with minimal modification where the variables are used as well as give me a strategy for dealing with this until VS better supports the standard.

Thank you

Comment: Is this C or C++? Pick a language. Also state where exactly you get the error, Which language standard you are compiling for?

Comment: @Olaf I removed the C++ tag. You are right, it does not belong. I also added the error message. I am compiling against the C++11 standard which I believe is the default for VS 2012, while not being fully implemented. After I can get it to compile, my rewrites will include C++14.

Comment: You removed the C++-tag, but are compiling for C++11? I think you should first get the tags and the standard right. And (again): **WHERE** do you get the error message **exactly**?

Comment: @Olaf the specific location is a file called swemptab.cpp, line 1067. It was a c file that I renamed. The instantiation and initialization occurs in the global namespace. There are no functions in this file.

Comment: Last comment: 1) If you compile as C++, use the C++ tag **only**! 2) If you change the extension you tell the compiler this is C++ code! 3) **C and C++ are **different** languages! 4) Do you see any line-numbers in your question? I'm not a clairvoyant, so how should I see where the error occurs? **Post a [mcve]!**

Comment: And: The "instance" is **defined**! Do not confuse these terms! Note also that a definintion implies a declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I cheated. I added a constructor to the plantbl structure. This works for my current situation and is in line with my plan to port the C app to C++. Later, I will have to rewrite the structures anyway. I had hoped to get several strategies for dealing with this that could apply to different environments (Compilers, operating systems, language versions, etc) so I could make incremental changes so that it would compile.

For VS2012 on WinX compiling as C++ against C++11 I did the following:
Note that this also compiles on OSX with XCode 5.0.2 using Apple LLVM 5.0 with GNC++11 selected for the dialect.
I included algorithm where the structure is defined so I could use std::copy.

```
#include <algorithm>
```

I changed the plantbl structure from

```
struct plantbl {
  char max_harmonic[9];
  char max_power_of_t;
  signed char *arg_tbl;
  double *lon_tbl;
  double *lat_tbl;
  double *rad_tbl;
  double distance;
};
```

to

```
struct plantbl {
  char max_harmonic[9];
  char max_power_of_t;
  signed char *arg_tbl;
  double *lon_tbl;
  double *lat_tbl;
  double *rad_tbl;
  double distance;

  plantbl(char MH[9], char MPoT, signed char* ArgT, double* LonT, double* LatT, double* RadT, double Dist)
    :max_power_of_t(MPoT), arg_tbl(ArgT), lon_tbl(LonT), lat_tbl(LatT), rad_tbl(RadT), distance(Dist) 
    { std::copy(max_harmonic, max_harmonic + 9, MH); }
};
```

The plantbl structure is defined in the global namespace.

I changed the declaration and instantiation from:

```
static struct plantbl mer404 = {
  { 11, 14, 10, 11,  4,  5,  2,  0,  0,},
  6,
  merargs,
  mertabl,
  mertabb,
  mertabr,
  3.8709830979999998e-01,
};
```

to

```
char mer404Temp[9] = { 11, 14, 10, 11,  4,  5,  2,  0,  0 };
plantbl mer404
(
  mer404Temp,
  6,
  merargs,
  mertabl,
  mertabb,
  mertabr,
  3.8709830979999998e-01
);
```

Note that I added an array and this also is in the global namespace. I made similar changes for the eight other instances as well.

This is probably the least effective solution, may have unintended consequences, and may not work. However, it compiles which allows me to move forward.

While researching this problem, I saw a lot of explanations but not many suggestions. If there are suggestions on dealing with the original issue, I welcome them.